# Error with bluepy library for scan devices using raspberry pi4

Tags: python, bluetooth

I run this code for scan bluetooth device with bluepy library on my raspberry Pi4

```
while True:
try:
    #10.0 sec scanning
    ble_list = ble.Scanner().scan(10)
    for dev in ble_list:
        print("rssi: {} ; mac: {}".format(dev.rssi,dev.addr))
except:
    raise Exception("Error occured")
```

but I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/prova2.py", line 4, in <module>
    devices = scanner.scan(10.0)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/bluepy/btle.py", line 885, in scan
    self.start(passive=passive)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/bluepy/btle.py", line 823, in start
    self._mgmtCmd("le on")
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/bluepy/btle.py", line 325, in _mgmtCmd
    raise BTLEManagementError("Failed to execute management command '%s'" % (cmd), rsp)
bluepy.btle.BTLEManagementError: Failed to execute management command 'le on' (code: 20, error: Permission Denied)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone know what the error is?
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

if I run the script in the terminal (with sudo), I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prova2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bluepy.btle as ble
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluepy-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/bluepy/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import btle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluepy-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/bluepy/btle.py", line 14, in <module>
    from queue import Queue, Empty
ImportError: No module named queue
```

And if I run the same script with python IDE Pycharm the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/prova2.py", line 6, in <module>
    ble_list = ble.Scanner().scan(10)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/bluepy/btle.py", line 885, in scan
    self.start(passive=passive)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/bluepy/btle.py", line 823, in start
    self._mgmtCmd("le on")
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/bluepy/btle.py", line 325, in _mgmtCmd
    raise BTLEManagementError("Failed to execute management command '%s'" % (cmd), rsp)
bluepy.btle.BTLEManagementError: Failed to execute management command 'le on' (code: 20, error: Permission Denied)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/prova2.py", line 10, in <module>
    raise Exception("Error occured")
Exception: Error occured
```

Instead, if I use execute the script in terminal with python3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prova2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bluepy.btle as ble
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bluepy'
```

Comment: I execute the program with PyCharm IDE, not in the terminal

Comment: Yes, I tried with sudo but the error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prova2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bluepy.btle as ble
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluepy-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/bluepy/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import btle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluepy-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/bluepy/btle.py", line 14, in <module>
    from queue import Queue, Empty
ImportError: No module named queue

Comment: My assumption is PyCharm has created a Python3 Virtual environment (venv) for your project and you have installed `bluepy` into that venv. When you run inside PyCharm you don't have `root` permissions. And when you run from the terminal you are not pointing at the venv with `bluepy` installed. When you "run" in PyCharm at the top of the `run` tab the first line will be the python and script location (something like `/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/venv/bin/python /home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/prova2.py` ). Copy that line to the terminal and put a `sudo` in front of it